# TinyMCE plugin creation callback not running until second load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce-4

I am attempting to add in a third party plugin to TinyMCE that is built to connect language-tool and TinyMCE. The plugin will load and work properly only after the second time the page is loaded. The plugin is properly created here

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('languagetool', function(editor, url) {
```

and added to the TinyMCE plugin list here

```
 config.plugins = 'languagetool link lists paste';
```

When loading the page the first time, I receive the following error.

> [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXb7N.png)

TinyMCE does not load the editor box at all. After switching to a different page and back, the error no longer appears but the TinyMCE editor (with some plugin functionality) is now visible and is able to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing running code it will be difficult for anyone to give you a specific thought on why this is happening.  Any time I see:

```
Cannot set property 'xxxxxxx' of null
```

...this typically means that some code assumes a variable has a value when its `null`.  For example I could try to execute:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
```

...but if there is no active editor then `tinymce.activeEditor` is `null` and you can't execute the `getContent()` on `null`.  In your scenario some part of the code is trying to run the `onload` method but the object on which that is being called is `null`.

You need to figure out what line of code is causing that and then figure out why a variable is `null` when it is expected to be something else.